# IntelliJ: Generate switch case

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there really no way to generate a switch case for a given variable in IntelliJ?

Ctrl+Space as well as Ctrl+J yield no results.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

For enum variables, enter `switch (myEnumVar)` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Smart completion will suggest: `Create missing 'switch' branches`

[Crazy Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) provided the following screenshot showing how to enable the **Create Enum Switch Branches** intention.

[image: Intention: Create Enum Switch Branches]

See [YouTrack issue 6374](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6374).

Comment: This feature is provided by the **Create Enum Switch Branches** intention that needs to be enabled: http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/6195/20120919130903.png.

Comment: I was hoping to find a more general solution like a template for ints.

Answer (score 14):

Follow the steps here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Creating+and+applying+live+templates+(code+snippets)

for the context, use JAVA and the code for a switch - case Statement would be:

```
switch($switchVar$) {
case $value$:
    $END$
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Do the same for try - catch ;)

```
try {
$END$
} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I love the template function in intellij and use it a lot.

Comment: [Here is updated docs on creating live templates in intelliJ.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) I just copied and pasted above text in IDE, saves time thanks @Fabian

Comment: No this template will not autocomplete all the enum vars