# Intellij equivalent of Eclipse syso

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to switch from eclipse to Intellij.
Immediatelly I have found a problem. 
In the eclipse you can type:

```
syso
```

and the presss:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE BAR</kbd>

and this will result in:

```
System.out.println
```

What is the equivalent shortcut in Intellij?

Comment: Check this answer for the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492205/newbie-to-intellij-idea-cant-not-find-system-out-println

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479002/synonyms-of-sout-tab-shortcut-in-intellij-ide-for-myeclipse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479002/synonyms-of-sout-tab-shortcut-in-intellij-ide-for-myeclipse

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479002/synonyms-of-sout-tab-shortcut-in-intellij-ide-for-myeclipse

Comment: go through this link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479002/synonyms-of-sout-tab-shortcut-in-intellij-ide-for-myeclipse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479002/synonyms-of-sout-tab-shortcut-in-intellij-ide-for-myeclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Equivalent shortcut in IntelliJ is `sout`

Just type `sout` you will get list of shortcut. Choose your option what you want to write and then press enter.

**All shortcut to print string in IntelliJ:**

`sout + TAB` Prints a string to System.out

`souf + TAB` Prints a formatted string to System.out

`soutm + TAB` Prints current class and method name to System.out

`soutp + TAB` Prints method parameter names and values to System.out

`soutv + TAB` Prints a value to System.out

Comment: Is there anything like this only for switch statements in InteliJ?

Comment: @Tim Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486846/intellij-generate-switch-case

Answer (score 1):

Just write `sout` and press `Tab`.